# Проверить есть ли в строке кириллица

Tags: c++, строки, g++

Есть код, который переводит верхний регистр в нижний.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    std::string text;
    std::cout << "Type text(QWERTY): ";
    std:: getline(std::cin, text);
    std::cout<<text << " - " ;
    std::transform(text.begin(), text.end(), text.begin(), tolower);
    std::cout << text;
return 0;
```

}

Но, если вводится кириллица, то кириллица не заменяется на нижний регистр. Как сделать проверку, есть ли кириллица или какой способ замены использовать, чтобы не нужно было использовать char и массивы char. Работа только со string

Comment: Установить локаль.

Comment: @alexolut Установил - не заработало

Comment: У вас сейчас два вопроса в одном. Определитесь конкретнее, что вы хотите - найти кириллицу или корректно преобразовать регистр?

Comment: `std::wstring` вам поможет

Comment: @МаксимДонец могу ошибаться, и времени нет писать код, но у каждого символа в юникоде есть определённый номер. По сути задачу нужно свести к проверке, является данный символ из соответствующего диапазона значений.

Comment: Все ascii символы (не кириллица) и в однобайтных кодировках и в utf-8, рассматриваемые как `unsigned char`,  будут меньше 128. Вот так и можно проверить, даже не зная точно кодировки.

Comment: Если вы хотите работать только со string, то откажитесь от кирилицы - сделайте провеку на соответствие вводу. Если строка содержит символы не из ASCII то не обрабатывайте такой ввод. Иначе только wstring.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `wstring`, `wcout`, `towlower`.

```
std::setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "ru-RU");
std::wstring text = L"ABC АБВ";
std::wcout << text << " - ";
std::transform(text.begin(), text.end(), text.begin(), towlower);
std::wcout << text << std::endl;
```

Выводит `abc абв`.

Comment: Сделал как вы посоветовали - ничего не выводит совсем. А если просто скопировать ваш пример, то вместо кириллицы выводит знаки вопроса